# PHP Email Form Redirects To Blank Page Plus Fails Sending

Tags: php, html, forms

I am just diving into some web development here. I have made a form within an index page. I have used some resources from around the web to build this page.

I am currently stuck with a form I have built. This form is on the main page. [PHP Email Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdXLj.png)

Every time it submits, it re-directs to a blank page, I am guessing my php page.

Here is the code for the form

**Edited code**

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 form_area">
  <form action="contact_process.php" method="post" class="row m0 appointment_home_form2">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
    </button>
    <h2 class="title">BOOK<br>NOW</h2>
    <div class="form_inputs row m0">
      <div class="row m0 input_row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p0">
          <label for="app_fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_fname" name="contact_fname" placeholder="Your First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p0">
          <label for="app_lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="app_lname" name="contact_lname" placeholder="Your Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m0 input_row">
        <label for="app_femail">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="app_femail" name="contact_femail" placeholder="Enter your Email Address">
      </div>
      <div class="row m0 input_row">
        <label for="app_fphone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="app_fphone" name="contact_fphone" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number">
      </div>
      <div class="row m0 input_row">
        <label for="app_date">Booking Date</label>
        <div class="input-append date">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="app_date" placeholder="Select the Appointment Date">
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m0 input_row">
        <label for="app_texts">Message</label>
        <textarea id="app_texts" class="form-control" name="contact_fmessage" placeholder="Write down the Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="book your appointment now">
    </div>
    <div class="row m0 form_footer">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/call-now3.png" alt="">555 555 5555</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Edited PHP**

```
<?php

    $to = "[myEmail]";
    $from = $_POST['contact_femail'];
    $name = $_POST['contact_fname'];
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $subject = "Hi Doctor, You have a message from" . $from;


    $fields = array();
    $fields["First Name"] = "contact_fname";
    $fields["Last Name"] = "contact_lname";
    $fields["Email"] = "contact_femail";
    $fields["Phone Name"] = "contact_fphone";
    $fields["Message"] = "contact_fmsg";

    $body = "Here is what was sent:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_POST[$a]); }

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Hopefully I formatted this correctly. Tried my best to make it clean and such.

Comment: Your `$fields` array does not look syntactically correct to me. Additionally, do you have error reporting turned on for your code ?

Comment: `$fields{"First Name"}` should be `$fields['First Name']` and so on.

Comment: Also I see no names on your form fields - you'll have no data coming through

Comment: I also don't see `name` attribute in some of your form inputs.

Comment: @Maximus2012 so as an example. For the _first name_ label, I want to put `name="contact_fname" ` in there?

Comment: @Michael that is correct. Then you can access it on the back-end either via `$_POST['contact_fname']` or via `$_REQUEST['contact_fname']`. I would recommend `$_POST` over `$_REQUEST` since you have explicitly specified `method=POST` when declaring your form.

Comment: @Maximus2012 when I submit now, the address bar contains this _mywebsite/contact_process.php?contact_fname=Testin&contact_lname=Testing+Last&contact_femail=testing%40testing.com&contact_fphone=555555555&date=02%2F06%2F2016&contact_fmessage=testing+testing_

Comment: @Michael that could be because your input method is `GET` and not `POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you defined `id` attributes in your `input` tags, but not `name` attributes (which is how they are appear in your actual form POST) like this (which you did in your edit)):

```
<input type="text" id="app_fname" name="contact_fname" placeholder="Your First Name"/>
```

Also considering the amount of information you are sending (and the common approach to dealing with form submissions) you should define your `method` attribute in your `form` like this:

```
<form action="contact_process.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Just added some more information about defining thew HTTP method to use for your `form`, other than that I think you are good (though the point about using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST is a good suggestion, it comes down to code preference, if you wanted to support passing values in $_COOKIES, $_GET or $_POST then $_REQUEST would be fine)

Comment: I edited my code and code in the original post to what I understand it should be, but still no luck :(